# Progress bar while using DropBox api

Tags: c#, dropbox

Using Dropnet ( dropbox api) . I can upload a file like this:

```
        DropNet.DropNetClient dc = new DropNet.DropNetClient("*************", "g86p9959v9tvg49");
        dc.Login("jain@gmail.com", "********");
        byte[] rawData = File.ReadAllBytes("Ionic.Zip.dll");
         dc.UploadFile("Public", "Ionic.Zip.dll",rawData );
        Console.WriteLine(dc.Account_Info().quota_info.quota/(1024*1024));
```

Is there  a way to have a progress bar with this ? [It says here:](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=20180)

> Its something you can work out
> yourself - you know how big the files
> are, you know how much you have sent
> or received so far, the rest is basic
> math. :)

How do I figure out how much data has been sent ? any help please ?

Thanks

Edit:
the upload method returns - DropNet.Models.DropNetResult.statuscode a System.net.httpstatuscode object. Is this it ? Do I have to somehow use this thing to make a progress bar ?

Comment: You'll have to either get feedback from `dc.UploadFile` or from the server. It sounds like they're intending you to do it on the client; you'll have to dig into `UploadFile` to see if there's any scope to add progress callbacks, or to update a shared variable that some other thread can (carefully) read, or something else. (As an aside: is there no upload stream or upload direct from filename API? Read-in-bytes-then-upload will start struggling if you ever get many gigabyte files.)

Comment: thanks, I am still exploring the api to see if there is a better way

Comment: Your edit: no, that's too late - the upload will be complete by then. You need to get the actual UploadFile operation to return you back progress information as it's going along. If it doesn't already support this then you may need to dig into the implementation itself, find the code which actually performs the upload and modify that to return you progress as it goes along. If it's uploading from an array of bytes you can probably hook into that (e.g. if it's a single write then switch it to a for-loop of partial writes and call back between each).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible looking at [their source code](https://github.com/dkarzon/DropNet/blob/master/DropNet/Client/Files.Sync.cs) on git-hub as there is no feedback what so ever. There is an [UploadFileAsync()](https://github.com/dkarzon/DropNet/blob/master/DropNet/Client/Files.Async.cs) that takes the same parameters as `UploadFile()` in addition to a callback Action that's called on completion. You could use the asynchronous method to show a marquee style progressbar and clean up on the callback Action.

I'm not sure if this will work but you could capture the quota_info before upload and start async upload and keep monitoring the quota_info periodically. If quota_info is updated as the file is uploaded then you know the size of the file and how much of it has been uploaded and you should be able to do the math.

Comment: checking quota seems clever but an erroneous way to report progress since concurrently files could be added/deleted from other synced devices/API consumers.